# Normal map changes from brushed metal to small square dents after texture paint and saving it

Tags: texturing, normal-map, saving

So I've been editing a normal map for a metal texture through texture paint to get some bumps on areas where the metal is rusty. The normal map originally gives the metal kind of a brushed finish look, but after saving it, the normal map changes completely into small square divots and dents. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your work as multiple Blender screen capture to ease the readers task. Are you talking about normal map or displacement map?  Blender users often [bake] normal maps.  Blender users can hand paint displacement maps.  I believe attempting to manually paint a normal map is rare, nearly impossible .. or even worse.  Suggestion add a new displacement texture.  Manually paint the displacement texture if you  choose.  See a video tutorial on using multiple textures to create a final look. The website which has a name that rhymes with noonube is available.

Comment: It's a normal map, not a displacement map. I'm not yet familiar with baking and how to bake textures, so I haven't been doing that. As for the painting, I'm not hand painting the whole thing, I'm just painting over small areas for more defined bumps to make the rust more realistic on the metal texture.

Comment: My original comment stands.  Please See multiple tutorials. They will save you time.  I will let you do your work.  A plus.

Comment: Alright, Thanks